# does gdb has something similar to struct command of crash utility

Tags: gdb, crash-dumps

I want to dump the internal data structures of ovs-vswitchd.

```
(gdb) print/x all_dpif_backers
$11 = {
    map = {
        buckets = 0x7e0e28,
        one = 0x23467f0,
        mask = 0x0,
        n = 0x1
    }
}
```

Now I know 0x23467f0 is the address of struct hmap_node.  If using crash
utility, I can dump the value like this:
crash> struct hmap_node 0x23467f0
How can we do this using gdb?

Comment: Maybe I should do it like this:
 p/x (struct shash_node)*0x23467f0

Answer (score 0):

> How can we do this using gdb?

```
(gdb) print *(struct hmap_node*) 0x23467f0
```

Or

```
(gdb) print (struct hmap_node*) 0x23467f0
$1 = ...
(gdb) print *$1
```

See also GDB [pretty printing](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html).